# set routes in CL basic

Tags: machine-code

I am trying to change the booting route in CL basic for a  WO1997012277 Device. I have added the C¿x? delegated however my code does not work.

```
  RA¿cl?=C¿x?/C¿OMAX? > V¿LCMAX?/(V¿CLMIN? - V¿CLMAX?)
```

Please help

```
____▒▒▒▒▒
—-▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
—–▓▓▓░░▓░
—▓░▓░░░▓░░░
—▓░▓▓░░░▓░░░
—▓▓░░░░▓▓▓▓
——░░░░░░░░
—-▓▓▒▓▓▓▒▓▓
–▓▓▓▒▓▓▓▒▓▓▓
▓▓▓▓▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓
░░▓▒░▒▒▒░▒▓░░
░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░
░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░
—-▒▒▒ ——▒▒▒
–▓▓▓———-▓▓▓
▓▓▓▓———-▓▓▓▓
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this part of the code "C¿OMAX?" it should be C?OMAX?